# How to get the context

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need to get the context to be able to get a resource.  Like this:

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource( R.raw.texture );
```

I've seen the getApplicationContext() in the android documentation but when I try to use it in the above code it doesn't work - it doesn't exist.

I can send the context through functions to get it to where it's needed and it works.  However, I find it cumbersome to send a variable through many functions that doesn't need or use it.  Then I would rather just try to get it in the function that do.  But the getApplicationContext(), as in the android documentation, doesn't work - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

So how do I get the context so I can read resources?  Or are my only option to send it through all my functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getApplicationContext()` is a method of a Context. You have to have a context to get the resources. That's just how it works.

Just makes sure you're not storing a reference to your context anywhere or you could cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you can use getResources() method immediately. For example

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
```

If you want to get some resource in some other class not in activity, you should pass context link in other class from your activity. For example

```
Util.convertLogo(this)
```

or

```
Util.convertLogo(getApplicationContext())
```